# Why would you fear if he's rich?

Tags: tehilim-psalms

[Tehilim 49:17-18](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.49.17-18?lang=bi)

> אַל־תִּ֭ירָא כִּֽי־יַעֲשִׁ֣ר אִ֑ישׁ כִּֽי־יִ֝רְבֶּה כְּב֣וֹד בֵּיתֽוֹ׃
>   כִּ֤י לֹ֣א בְ֭מוֹתוֹ יִקַּ֣ח הַכֹּ֑ל לֹא־יֵרֵ֖ד אַחֲרָ֣יו כְּבוֹדֽוֹ׃
>
> Do not be afraid when a man becomes rich, when his household goods
>   increase; for when he dies he can take none of it along; his goods
>   cannot follow him down.

What does it mean 'Do not be afraid'? Why should you be afraid when a man becomes rich?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This verse is referring to a wicked man. If you see a wicked man getting rich, do not wonder how is it so, for he does not take his riches when he dies.

And the 'fear' here is that a person may fear that it seems like there is no reward and punishment for good and bad, because he sees a wicked man who is enjoying life. So the Tehillim says "Do not fear", earthly possessions last only till death. (And then he will be judged for all his deeds.)